# Xamarin Forms/Prism/Shiny Dryly.ContainerException when registering service

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, shiny, prism

I'm having trouble with registering a platform specific service (iOS). This used to work fine, but now when running the app I get the following exception:

```
DryIoc.ContainerException: code: Error.UnableToResolveUnknownService;
message: Unable to resolve resolution root PS.Forms.VoiceApp.Base.Interfaces.IInitService
  from container with scope {Name=null}
 with Rules with {TrackingDisposableTransients, UseDynamicRegistrationsAsFallbackOnly, FuncAndLazyWithoutRegistration, SelectLastRegisteredFactory} and without {ThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient, UseFastExpressionCompilerIfPlatformSupported}
 with FactorySelector=SelectLastRegisteredFactory
 with Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments}
Where no service registrations found
  and no dynamic registrations found in 1 of Rules.DynamicServiceProviders
  and nothing found in 0 of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers
  at DryIoc.Throw.It (System.Int32 error, System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1, System.Object arg2, System.Object arg3) [0x00000] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:13642
  at DryIoc.Container.TryThrowUnableToResolve (DryIoc.Request request) [0x0006d] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:1088
  at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IContainer.ResolveFactory (DryIoc.Request request) [0x00072] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:1068
  at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCache (System.Int32 serviceTypeHash, System.Type serviceType, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) [0x00021] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:367
  at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve (System.Type serviceType, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) [0x0011c] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:356
  at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve (System.Type serviceType, System.Object serviceKey, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, System.Type requiredServiceType, DryIoc.Request preResolveParent, System.Object[] args) [0x00039] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:428
  at DryIoc.Resolver.Resolve (DryIoc.IResolver resolver, System.Type serviceType, System.Object[] args, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, System.Type requiredServiceType, System.Object serviceKey) [0x00000] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:8087
  at Prism.DryIoc.DryIocContainerExtension.Resolve (System.Type type, System.ValueTuple`2[System.Type,System.Object][] parameters) [0x0001c] in /_/src/Containers/Prism.DryIoc.Shared/DryIocContainerExtension.cs:294
```

I don't know why this would happen all of a sudden. In my AppDelegate.cs I register the IOSInitService which implements the Interface IInitService like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions) {
            this.PreventLinkerFromStrippingCommonLocalizationReferences();
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
            this.ShinyFinishedLaunching(new VoiceAppStartup {
                RegisterPlatformServices = services =>
                {
                    services.AddSingleton<IInitService, IOSInitService>();
                }
            });
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            FormsControls.Touch.Main.Init();
            this.LoadApplication(new App());
            return base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);
        }
```

I also register some other services in the App.xaml (which I can't do here with platform specific implementations) an they work fine:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) {
            containerRegistry.RegisterPopupNavigationService();
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppInfo, AppInfoImplementation>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IShare, ShareImplementation>();
...}
```

Does anybody have an idea why that could be? The exception implies, that the service is not registered or am I missing something?

Comment: Since the origin of when this happened seem a little cryptic, I haven't worked on the app for some time and in the meantime a lot of stuff has been updated (Vs, nuget packages). I'm gonna gradually downgrade all those packages soon to see if I can find where the issue lies, but maybe somebody has an idea what package could be the culprit

Comment: I don't use shiny or prism, but I notice error says `Where no service registrations found
  and no dynamic registrations found`. Sounds like a registration has been attempted BEFORE the registrar is ready. `this.ShinyFinishedLaunching(new VoiceAppStartup...` looks like a callback, that might happen later? Breakpoints on `services.AddSingleton...` and `override void RegisterTypes` - do they happen in wrong order?

Comment: I checked and `this.ShinyFinishedLaunching(...)` happens before `RegisterTypes()`. Do you think, this should be the other way around?

Comment: No, that is the correct order. My only other idea is vague: for unknown reason `DryIoc.Resolve` isn't using that `RegisterPlatformServices`; its looking somewhere else, which is `null`. Need an expert with `shiny` and/or `prism`.

Comment: Ok yeah, that's a rather niche issue. But thanks for the idea :)